# Hide custom cursor on hover over selected div

Tags: wordpress, cursor

I have a custom cursor with some hover effects on a page (wordpress). This custom cursor shall hide, when hovering a certain div, due to some text. Please take a look here: https://florianwmueller.com/work-test/
I tried a lot, including some javascript, but nothing works. Any idea?
I gave the pictures a special class: .no-cursor

Thankful for any help...

Answer (score 0):

Add this script on your website.

```
<script>
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("no-cursor");
var style;

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        style = document.createElement("style");
        style.innerHTML = "body.cursor-element-shape a { cursor: default !important; } .wpcc-active > .wpcc-cursor { display: none !important; }";
        document.head.appendChild(style);
    });
  
    elements[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
        document.head.removeChild(style);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, tha't exactly what I was looking for. Learned a lot about js the last days... I changed "cursor: default" to "cursor: none", so I only have the text/title.