# hide cursor on class

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onmouseover, mousehover

on the website https://florianwmueller.com/work-alternative/ (a testpage) I have several images with the class .no-cursor. Then I have this little javascript below:

```
<script>
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("no-cursor");
var style;

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        style = document.createElement("style");
        style.innerHTML = "body.cursor-element-shape a { cursor: none !important; } .wpcc-active > .wpcc-cursor { display: none !important; }";
        document.head.appendChild(style);
    });
  
    elements[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
        document.head.removeChild(style);
    });
}
</script>
```

The goal is that this script prevents any mouse pointer from being visible when hovering the corresponding images. This has worked well so far, but after an update of the plugin "Custom Cursor" it no longer works. Can you tell me why?
The goal is that this script prevents any mouse pointer from being visible when hovering the corresponding images, also the custom cursor. This has worked well so far, but suddenly not anymore. Anyone any idea?

Comment: Please share your html and css code as well to better understand how you are implementing it. Else, you can create a jsfiddle for the same. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but sharing the css and html would be too much, since it is a wordpress page with a huge load of extra-css. I try to narrow it down a bit...

Comment: @Yogi No, there is the possibility of including additional elements, not excluding them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using css like this:

```css
.no-cursor{
  cursor:none; /*Setting the cursor to be invisible*/
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico" alt="image" class="no-cursor">
```

If it is still showing then that means something is overriding it, and in this case add `!important` after none

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried that before, no effect.

Comment: did you try !important

Comment: Yes, of course. The original help also came from the forum here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75363204/hide-custom-cursor-on-hover-over-selected-div/75365486#75365486

The thing is that the developer of the custom-cursor works with css and javascript. css is not my problem, my js knowledge is unfortunately (still) limited. The developer is unfortunately not available at the moment...